# Optimal way to ensure data integrity in Python

Tags: python, json, api, data-integrity, python-collections

**tl;dr**:

In Python is there a performant means of data integrity validation?

**Synopsis:**

I'm working on a framework that **(A)** ingests similar types of data from multiple API services that can be built out by developers, **(B)** allows users/developers to create integrations with the data pipeline, then **(C)** returns to interacting with the same or new API services.

*Data flow:*
**A** -> **B** -> **C**

The **3** primary facilities the framework offers is:

1. A shared context for a given API (allows for rate limiting facilities, account credentials, etc.)
2. A shared context for the various data integration components (allows for one actor to generate useful output for a later actor in the pipeline).
3. The actual data that gets passed in from the API (may be websocket or periodic/scheduled API responses).

**Requirements:**

With this, I need **3** sets of *types* of data.  Within each of those sets, the data will have the following requirements:

1. A single Python `type` to encompass any incoming JSON structure.
2. The objects should be immutable.
3. Needs to be performant.  The goal is to have as near-realtime API interactions as is possible.

**Nice to have:**

1. The ability to define the types minimalistically in groupings or definition files.
2. The attributes should be referencable by name, key, etc.
3. Should be able to serialize to/from JSON efficiently.
4. Security is a concern here too -- we want to trust the data hasn't been manipulated, and in some cases we want to filter it of sensitive values.

**Where it's at now:**

This project started out using `namedtuples` to translate `dict`-like JSON structures, but it's needing quite a bit of expansion.  For example: while two different APIs have objects that are mostly similar, the actors on that data need it to be congruent.  This requires a translation layer for each API, creating an additional set of object definitions for every API, and is making the demands on the `namedtuples` library way more complex and cumbersome.

The next step was for me to either create a `metaclass` that generates immutable objects based on pre-defined structures, or to subclass `namedtuples`, adding several helper methods.

With that, I thought I would reach out to the community and see if any of you had any ideas before I roll my own.

Comment: your case sounds complex, but I guess all you need is [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like it will go a bit beyond fitting the bill, and rolling my own sounds like a lot of work. I'll build out a `marshmallow` implementation on an alternate branch and answer my own question with the details. Thanks, @georgexsh!